# Javascript async/await : undefined error on file read

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, file-read

I am trying to send the email with for loop using `async/await`.

```
const prepareNotification =(genie)=>{
    genie.forEach(async (item)=>{
        if(item.is_active){

            if(item.is_email){
                sendEmailNotification(item);
            }

        }else{
            console.log('deal genie inactive for',item.name);
        }
    });
}
```

For sending, I need to read the HTML from a file and send to the mail function.

```
const sendEmailNotification=async (item)=>{
    try{

        let emailTemplate = await fs.readFile(__basedir+'/controllers/html/sharedeal.html','utf-8');
        console.log(emailTemplate);
        let replacements = {
            dealLink:'testlinkhere'
           };
        let mailOptions = {
                   from: process.env.smtpEmail,
                   to: item.email,
                   subject: 'DealLink',
                   replacements:replacements,
                   template:emailTemplate
           };
        let mail = await sendEmail(mailOptions);
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
   }
}
```

but I am getting `undefined` on `console.log(emailTemplate);`, one more question how can i make sure  that the `sendEmailNotification` is execute one after another on each state in the for loop??

Comment: `Array.forEach` does not support the `async`. Or, if you want to see that in another way, it does **not** support a promise as a callback response. You need to do an **ordered async loop** or similar, otherwise it won't work. Besides, you should do `await sendEmailNotification`, otherwise the async will be useless anyway.

Comment: so i need to use something like in  `waterfall` method in async library

Comment: Whatever you're going to use, you can do that by performing a simple recursive loop: https://pastebin.com/mZbCi5UB .

Comment: Did you promisify `fs.readFile`? It normally doesn't return a promise.

Comment: Indeed, fs.readFile is synchronous, unless promisified...

Comment: @briosheje `fs.readFile` is not synchronous, it is asynchronous but expects a node-style callback (where the first argument is error)

Comment: @slebetman sorry, I meant that it does **not** return a promise. It won't work with **await**, unless promisified, bad esplanation from my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.readFile` doesn't support `async/await`. But you can create a version that does:

```
const util = require('util');
const readFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
```

and then

```
let emailTemplate = await readFileAsync(__basedir+'/controllers/html/sharedeal.html','utf-8');
console.log(emailTemplate);
```

---

> how can i make sure that the sendEmailNotification is execute one after another on each state in the for loop??

```
const prepareNotification = async (genie) => {
    for (let item of genie) {
        if(item.is_active){

            if(item.is_email){
                await sendEmailNotification(item);
            }

        }else{
            console.log('deal genie inactive for', item.name);
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
const prepareNotification = (genie) => {
    genie.reduce((prev, item) => {
        if(item.is_active){

            if(item.is_email){
                return prev.then(() => sendEmailNotification(item));
            }

        }else{
            console.log('deal genie inactive for', item.name);
        }
        return prev;
    }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Comment: Its worked BTW do you have any suggestion for my last sentence??

Comment: There is no need to return a promise from  `sendEmailNotification`??

Comment: @iambatman It already does return a `Promise`, it's an `async` function.